# Playing .mp4 in Pyside Phonon without K-Lite

Tags: pyside, backend, codec, phonon

I'm developing a media player using PySide and Phonon. My player cannot play .mp4 files or many other file types unless the K-Lite codec pack is installed.

Is there any way to package the needed codecs/backend with my program, preventing the need for my users to go and install K-Lite to their computers? Thanks!

Comment: This isn't what you're asking, but `Phonon.BackendCapabilities.isMimeTypeAvailable(mimetypes.guess_type(urllib.pathname2url(path))[0])`
will get you to be able to dynamically detect if the mimetype is available. From there you can prompt the user. 

It stands to reason you could find the location of the codecs and package them. How to do this, I am not sure. Also check the licenses of the codec(s) you are packaging